# Unable to retrieve deployment version of static files from the file system

Tags: magento2, static-content

I asked my hosting site to update PHP so that I could configure **Payzone** to **Magento 2**. It seems that it may have upset something as when I try to go on the website, magento admin or File zilla I get an error message or Unable to retrieve deployment version of static files from the file system.

I've asked the hosting site to take a look, but they don't think that it's a problem at their end. Does anyone have any idea how I might fix this.

Comment: As you've added a php 5.4 tag , i would like to remind you that magento 2 doesnt work on it - http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html

Comment: Could you ignore the tag

Comment: what magento version are you running

Comment: I'm running magento 2

Answer (score 13):

Seems you have converted your store from the developer mode to the production mode and now the system is not able to create the folders and files automatically.

For the same, try below steps

php bin/magento cache:clean

php bin/magento cache:flush

remove everything(not .htacess) from pub/static, var, generated

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_AU --exclude-theme Magento/luma --exclude-theme Magento/blank -f

Here you go, check your frontend and admin, it should work like it should be. Enjoy